# Java SE server + database + rest framework

Tags: java, database, rest

I am looking for JAVA SE EMBEDDED SOLUTION (simple server+database+(optional) rest framework). I would avoid GlassFish, |Tomcat and so on.  I have found Oracle JAVA EMBEDDED SUITE. This solution sounds pretty, but it is restricted for x86 linux architecture. Well, what is the best solution of this type?

Answer (score 2):

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) + [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) + Embedded DB of your choice should work just fine. There are lots of embedded databases to pick from - [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) are just a few.

Comment: And here is a [Getting Started Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/getting-started.html)